# Store Function highlight (local storage)

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

I want to store this code to local storage (browser cookie), can anyone plz help.

```
<li onclick="highlight(this)" id="highlight"<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="ui-sortable-handle"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/<?php echo $row['image_name'];
                      
                ?>" alt=""></a></li>


    function highlight(e) {
    if (e.style.backgroundColor) {
        e.style.backgroundColor = null;
    } else {
        e.style.backgroundColor = "#F55302";
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to store a function in the localStorage as it just accepts strings so you need to serialize it. Please explain why you want to do that.

Comment: I have multiple images on a website. When the user clicks on an image. The image is highlighted. The next time the visitor visits the website, the image should still be highlighted. Until he removed it. (personal pages)

Comment: Then you just need to store imageId or something to identify it when you visit page again.

Comment: Okay, do you have a example code? This would help a lot.